# MySQL SET field where column A + Column B matches search

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a query in MySQL where I want to match a value (e.g. 1234Test)
to two fields in the table. If it doesn't match I want it to look for another row.

e.g.

```
UPDATE test_table

SET column_code = "input variable"

WHERE sid = '1122233'

AND gid = '11'

AND (
     qid + title = '1234Test 
  OR
     qid = '1234'
)
```

Now this doesn't work. I also tried to see if there is a way to do this with a CASE WHEN
statement, but cannot figure out how that should work.

Can you please give me some hints and tips about how to proceed?

Comment: What is qid and title datatypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `CONCAT()` to concatenate fields.

```
UPDATE test_table
SET    column_code = "input variable"
WHERE  sid = '1122233' AND
       gid = '11' AND 
       (CONCAT(qid, title) = '1234Test' OR qid = '1234')
```

Comment: Thanks, but this somehow does not work completely. When leaving out the "OR qid = '1234'" knowing that the CONCAT matches my '1234Test' it will not set the column code.   Somehow it doesn't seem to match.
Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Found it! 
I needed to also CAST the qid since this is a string